# printing list object with appended element not works - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, append

I have written a code to get list from tuple and append a number to it. I have read other posts about this, and know that list.append returns None, and None would be printed. But in my code, how can I append the new value? Thank you.

```
from itertools import combinations

steps = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
for i in range(7, 8):
    for subset in combinations(steps, i):
        tmp_subset = list(subset).append(1)
        print(tmp_subset)
```

Comment: `list.append()` returns `None`. You can use `tmp_subset = [*subset, 1]` or `tmp_subset = list(subset) ; tmp_subset.append(1)`

Answer (score 1):

As you said in your question you know that `list.append()` returns `None`, therefore you are currently setting `tmp_subset` to the value returned by `append()`. So all you need to do is separate your line `tmp_subset = list(subset).append(1)` into:

```
tmp_subset = list(subset)
tmp_subset.append(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use append in a print, as returns None! I changed the code as follows and it works:

```
from itertools import combinations

steps = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
for i in range(7, 8):
    #print(i)
    for subset in combinations(steps, i):
        tmp_subset = list(subset)
        tmp_subset.append(1)
        print(tmp_subset)
```